# Avoid resending data on page refresh

Tags: php, http, post-redirect-get

I'm writing simple login system & I'd like to do "GET" self-redirection to avoid resending data on refresh (POST-Redirect-GET pattern). As I know there are several ways doing that:

1. `header('Location:main.php');`
2. `echo '<body onload="window.location = \''.$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF'].'\'">body</body>';`
3. `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF'].'">';`

There are my quesions:

1. Which method is the most correct?
2. Why does the 3. method doesn't work?. It does redirect but after
   that when I click "refresh" button I still get the "Do you want to
   resend data" message?

Answer (score 0):

The "most correct" is `1.` because that is HTTP, just make sure you are returning a temporary redirect code, otherwise users with proxies will eventually end up unable to use your system. Other two rely on browser implementation (well technically 1. does too) and are not guaranteed to work.

However you should consider 4. using AJAX and not worrying about problems of the past century.

Comment: What do You mean "temporary redirect code"? Can You give an example?

Comment: Option one is the only real possibility to me. The other two are bad practice and show a lack of understanding of how the application should be designed if they are what you end up using

Comment: Can You please explain me why the other are bad? I'm beginner in programming.